# Pymongo- Check if the document is inserted properly when insert_one function is used

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm using **insert_one** function in pymongo to insert a single document to a collection. And the function returns me an instance of **pymongo.results.InsertOneResult**

From the **pymongo.results.InsertOneResult** that is returned after using insert_one function, how can I check if the document got inserted without any errors in runtime?

Comment: You can check [Inserted Count](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.BulkWriteResult.inserted_count). Surround your code is try catch using appropriate [Pymongo Exceptions](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#module-pymongo.errors)

Comment: You can use `find_one('_id'=insertedIdhere)` with the value of insertedId from the returned InsertOneResult object to check from the db if it is correctly added.

Answer (score 1):

Check inserted_id value

```
insert_result = connection[database][collection].insert_one(document)
if insert_result.inserted_id:
   print("success")
```